# Swift CGAffineTransformScale to a scale, not by a scale

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, cgaffinetransformscale

Let's say I scale a UILabel using a CGAffineTransformScale like so:

```
let scale = 0.5
text = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))
text.text = "Test"

UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
    self.text.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.text.transform, scale, scale)
}, completion: {(value : Bool) in
    print("Animation finished")
})
```

This works great when I want to scale the UILabel by half. But if I were to call this same code again, it would end up with a scale of 0.25, as it scales again by half.

Would it be possible to use the CGAffineTransformScale to always scale to a size of half the original UILabel frame, instead of a scaling it cumulatively?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Swift 3**:

```
text.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
   self.text.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
})
```

Answer (score 6):

You are scaling the existing transform. Just create a new transform:

```
self.text.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)
```

Comment: or `CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, scale, scale)`

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
self.text.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: scaleFactorX, y: scaleFactorY)
```